# "Enable HTTP Keep-Alive" in IIS cause disruption?

Tags: iis, iis-6

I have a production web site in IIS 6 where I need to change the value of the "Enable HTTP Keep-Alive" checkbox. Will that cause production disruptions? Recycles, app domain restarts, or similar?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're running (ASP.NET, PHP, etc.), you may or may not see any disruptions but you will see a big hit to your sites' performance.

Comment: Gracias. ASP.NET, if that matters, any considerations specific to it?

Comment: Not sure, however if you tell me what problem you're specifically trying to fix by disabling the keep alive, I, or someone else who finds this thread might be able to find a solution that fixes the problem without sacrificing performance. I have experience in running asp.net sites in IIS 6 so I would me more than happy to help.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's definitely not what most sites should do, but we have insane crazy proxies between a couple of tiers that go nuts without other things being set correctly.